# Background images failing to be linked in middleman. Why?

Tags: html, css, ruby, middleman

I'm using middleman to develop a static website and for some reason, the background-image refuses to load. I've done this before many times and I have no idea why It's not working.

Here I set the background image:

```
.background{
    width: 100%;
}

#topbackground{
    background-image: image-url("mountains.jpg");
    height: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Here is the fairly simple html:

```
<div class="background" id="topbackground">
</div>
```

But no background image loads, as you can see here: 
[image: background image load failure]

I have no conflicting stylesheets. The only other stylesheet this page is linked to is `normalize.css` and I've already tried neutralizing that, but it wasn't the issue.

The image is in the right directory, I have refreshed the server; is there any reason why the image would fail to load?

update: I've tried linking the image via an image tag using `<%= image_tag "mountains.jpg" %>` and it works just fine. It is just `image-url` in the scss file that is failing.

Comment: `background-image: url(mountains.jpg);` as long as the image resides in the same folder as the css file

Comment: It isn't. I'm using an external framework that allows me to use "image-url" to link to images in a specified image directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. My css file didn't have the `.scss` extension required for the use of the `image-url` helper.